# May Calmar ratio be considered to satisfy monotonicity?

Tags: risk, performance-evaluation, maximum-drawdown

We have the following definitions

$\text{Gain-loss ratio} = \frac{E[X^+]}{|E[X^-]|}=\frac{E[X^+]}{-E[X^-]}=\frac{E[X]}{-E[X^-]}+1$;

where $X$ are the returns, $E[X^+]$ is the expected gain, i.e. $E[X|X\ge 0]\times P[X\ge0]$, $E[X^-]$the expected loss i.e. $E[X|X< 0]\times P[X<0]$; and we have $E[X]=E[X^+]-E[X^-].$

$\text{Calmar ratio} = \frac{E[X]}{MDD}$

where $\text{MDD}$ is the Maximum DrawDown.

"Given a fixed time time horizon [0,T], with T > 0, and given two cumulative return paths  X,Y (stochastic processes with time index running over [0,T])  such that $X(\omega) < Y(\omega)$  pointwise (for every outcome $\omega$ in the sample space) , then it easily seen that there is not a unique ordering between their drawdowns, say D(X) and D(Y).  Both D(X) < D(Y) or D(X) > D(Y) are compatible with X(ω) < Y(ω) for every ω. In fact, it is only the running maximum   max_t X_t which is less than the running maximum   max_t Y_t, provided that X(ω) < Y(ω) for every ω."

*However, does there exist any exact example?*

I think the $X$,$Y$ should be the return series as opposed to the the cumulative return series.

More over less, the higher the better. Sharpe ratio does not satisfy monotonicity due to it violate "More over less". [Cherny and Madan (2009)](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article-abstract/22/7/2571/1599175) gave an example **very clear** to show that the Sharpe ratio does not satisfy monotonicity.

The Gain-loss ratio is considered to satisfy monotonicity.

However, may Calmar ratio (E[X]/MDD) be considered to satisfy monotonicity?

*Does here exist any ex-post example to demonstrate the gain-loss ratio satisfies monotonicity, but the Calmar ratio does not?*

Furthermore, for ex-post performance comparison, D(X) and D(Y) are fixed.

If X(ω) < Y(ω) for every ω,

if D(X) > D(Y), we have Calmar(X) < Calmar(Y),

```
      A. we can conclude Fund X not better than Fund Y.
```

if D(X) < D(Y), we may have two outcomes,

```
      B. if Calmar(X) < Calmar(Y), we can also conclude Fund X not better than Fund Y.

      C. if Calmar(X) > Calmar(Y), may we conclude Fund X is better than Fund Y?
```

If for C, we can conclude Fund X is better than Fund Y, Together with A and B, then may we say Calmar ratio is "monotone"?

If the Gain-Loss ratio is considered a monotone measure (ex-post), may Calmar ratio also be considered a monotone measure?

Comment: The ratio would be infinity for an investment that always returns zero. Now you can have a strategy whose cumulative returns are always above this zero return but have a smaller value for the Calmar ratio because it sometimes falls in value.